# issue with sending ajax message

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Newbie to JQuery / JSON / AJAX so please be nice.

I've pieced together this artwork from examples on SO and other sites, but I'm struggling.

I've created some functions to deal with the AJAX response...

```
function newOrderSuccess(response) { ... }
function newOrderTimeout() { ... }
function newOrderFail() { ... }
```

...

Here is the AJAX call:

```
function sendCallAjaxUsingJson(theUrl, theData, successCallbackFunction, timeoutCallbackFunction, otherErrorCallback, timeoutValueMilli)
{
var successFn = successCallbackFunction; 
var timeoutFn = timeoutCallbackFunction; 
var otherFn = otherErrorCallback;
if(!(typeof successFn === 'function') || !(typeof timeoutFn === 'function') || !(typeof otherFn === 'function')) 
        return false;
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: theUrl,
        timeout:timeoutValueMilli,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { json: JSON.stringify(theData) },
        success:successFn(result),
        error: function(x, t, m) {
                   if(t==="timeout") {
                        timeoutFn();
                    } else {
                        otherFn();
                    }
                }
    });
```

}

My code calls the function as follows:

```
sendCallAjaxUsingJson("/ordertaker.php", 'submitOrder','newOrderSuccess', 'newOrderTimeout', 'newOrderFail',1000);
```

The result is..... nothing. I was getting to the `newOrderFail()` function before I uploaded the `ordertaker.php` file, but now I get nothing.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please post errors from your browsers console. What is `sendCallAjaxUsingJson`? is it supposed to be `doCallAjaxUsingJson`?

Comment: What is nothing?  Are you seeing an outbound call in fiddler/firebug?  Or is it never initializing the call?  If you're getting an error, that's extremely valuable

Comment: @JacobParker Sorry, I was simplifying my code slightly to cut out the relevant components. it was supposed to be doCallAjaxUsingJson as you said. I updated it.

Comment: What are those other function doing? Calling some webservice?

Comment: Nope, the other function I was using was because I was reading somewhere that you could send `function(response {successFn(response); }` as a parameter, so I created an intermediary function named: `sendCallAjaxUsingJson` to intercept

Answer (score 1):

You are passing strings to `sendCallAjaxUsingJson` instead of functions,

```
sendCallAjaxUsingJson("/ordertaker.php", 'submitOrder',newOrderSuccess, newOrderTimeout, newOrderFail,1000);
```

Also you are calling your success function in your ajax call rather that setting it.

```
success:successFn,
```

Comment: You pointed out a few items and that got me a lot closer. Now it works for the timeout but I can't get the success function to run. It now just runs the fail (error) function. The script on the server just has an echo statement - so shouldn't this return a "success"?